# How to sort a string column as a date time column in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, gridview

I want to order a column in my grid view as a `datetime` but i feel it's ordered as a string instead :

## My code :

```
if (SortExpression.ToString() == "TransDate")
{
    if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        gv_Details1.DataSource = TransactionList.OrderBy(t =>  DateTime.Parse(t.TransDate)).ToList<UserTransactionDTO>();
    }
    else
    {
        gv_Details1.DataSource = TransactionList.OrderByDescending(t => DateTime.Parse(t.TransDate)).ToList<UserTransactionDTO>();
    }
}
```

---

## My aspx :

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="TransDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="TransDate">
```

---

Part of the result ::

```
23/12/2012 09:51
27/9/2012 11:36
3/10/2012 12:28
2/10/2012 10:51
```

Comment: umm... where is the "my code" section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your using `DateTime.Parse` in the linq sorting and your string has cases where the first and second parts could be the day or the month... remember the parsing is happening item by item so just because the first one parse one way doesn't mean the second one will parse the same way.

Your region default is probably month first which doesn't work for the first couple so it knows that the first part is day so it uses that format. For the last couple dates, the first part does work for month so it parses month first as per the default.  Or vice versa :)

Try using `DateTime.ParseExact` like this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";

gv_Details1.DataSource = TransactionList.
    OrderBy(t =>  DateTime.ParseExact(t.TransDate, format, provider)).
    ToList<UserTransactionDTO>();
```

Hopefully I picked the right format but if not just tweak it.

Comment: `CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                        string[] format = provider.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();

                        if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                        {

                            gv_Details1.DataSource = TransactionList.
                                OrderBy(t => DateTime.ParseExact(t.TransDate, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None)).
                                ToList<UserTransactionDTO>();`

                        }

Answer (score 2):

The result doesn't look string ordered to me... Below is a quick example of something that is sorting correctly that uses string parse and a list

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<String> datestrings = new List<string>()
    {
        "12/23/2012 09:51",
        "9/27/2012 11:36",
        "10/2/2012 12:28",
        "10/3/2012 10:51"
    };
    List<DateTime> dates = datestrings.Select(a => DateTime.Parse(a)).OrderBy(a => a).ToList();
    foreach (var d in dates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The above sorts your strings properly.

I would first make sure that the grid isn't reordering things on you after you set the dataset for some reason by storing `TransactionList.OrderBy(t =>  Da...` in a temporary variable and making sure it's ordering correctly before setting the datasource.

I would next check to see if it's a culture issue with your dates (or use ParseExact) (although nothing hits me from what you sent in it's current order).

Finally, and i'm not up to speed on asp bindings, but perhaps the way you are binding to teh dataset requires you to specify it's a date like the following link eludes to: http://forums.asp.net/t/1001482.aspx/1

an excerpt from the site recommends:

```
< asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did it by just SQL I added an 'order by' statement to the T-SQL code attached to the grid view.